# AsyncStorage.setItem not triggered in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, authentication, asyncstorage

I have prepared a structure for login operations, but after performing **AsyncStorage.setItem** in the signOut function, the application does not automatically redirect to the **AuthStorage** side. It stays on the page it was on. I experience the same thing when logging in, and when logging in, I set **setItem('true')** to but still stay on the page I am on, but when I refresh the application, the redirect occurs.

**App.js**

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'

import AppNavigator from './components/auth/AppNavigator';
import AuthNavigator from './components/auth/AuthNavigator'
import AuthStorage from './components/auth/storage';

const App = () => {
  const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    readData();
  }, []);

  const readData = async () => {
    try {
      const isLoggedIn = JSON.parse(await AuthStorage.getItem());
      console.log(isLoggedIn);
      
      if (isLoggedIn !== null) {
        setLoginStatus(isLoggedIn);
      }
      
    } catch (e) {
      alert('Failed to fetch the data from storage');
    }
  };

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {loginStatus ? <AppNavigator /> : <AuthNavigator />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**AuthNavigator.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";

import OnboardScreen from '../auth/OnboardScreen'
import LoginScreen from '../auth/LoginScreen'
import RegisterScreen from '../auth/RegisterScreen'

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const AuthNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Onboard" screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} independent={false}>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Onboard" component={OnboardScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
};

export default AuthNavigator;
```

**AppNavigator.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import {
    StatusBar,
    Image,
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableOpacity,
    View,
    ActivityIndicator
} from 'react-native'

//Main pages
import HomeScreen from '../../components/main/HomeScreen'
import SearchScreen from '../../components/main/SearchScreen'
import FavoriteScreen from '../../components/main//FavoriteScreen'
import AddPetScreen from '../../components/main/AddPetScreen'
import MessageScreen from '../../components/main/MessageScreen';
import PetDetailScreen from '../../components/main/PetDetailScreen'
import EditPetScreen from '../../components/main/EditPetScreen'
import ProfileScreen from '../../components/main/ProfileScreen';
import EditProfileScreen from '../../components/main/EditProfileScreen';
import PassivePets from '../../components/main/PassivePets';


import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";

import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons'

import { COLORS, images } from '../../constants'
const { plus } = images;

import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import { mainStore } from '../store/storeMain';


const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();


const CustomTabBarButton = ({ children, onPress, navigation }) => (
    <Animatable.View animation="slideInUp">
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={onPress}
            style={{
                top: -20,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                ...styles.shadow
            }}
        >
            <View style={{
                width: 70,
                height: 70,
                borderRadius: 35,
                backgroundColor: COLORS.bottomColor
            }}>
                {children}
            </View>

        </TouchableOpacity>
    </Animatable.View>

)

//Tab bar
const HomeTabs = () => {
    const { userName, imageUser, loading } = mainStore;
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator
            initialRouteName="Home"
            tabBarOptions={{
                activeTintColor: COLORS.appColor,
                showLabel: false,
            }}
        >
            <Tab.Screen
                name="Home"
                component={HomeScreen}
                options={{
                    tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (

                        <MaterialCommunityIcons
                            name="home"
                            color={color}
                            size={30}
                        />
                    ),

                }}
            />

            {
                userName ? (
                    <>
                        <Tab.Screen
                            name="Favorites"
                            component={FavoriteScreen}
                            options={{
                                tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (

                                    <MaterialCommunityIcons
                                        name="bookmark-outline"
                                        color={color}
                                        size={30}
                                    />
                                ),

                            }}
                        />
                        <Tab.Screen
                            name="AddPet"
                            component={AddPetScreen}
                            options={{
                                tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color }) => (
                                    <Image
                                        source={plus}
                                        resizeMode="contain"
                                        style={{
                                            width: 30,
                                            height: 30,
                                            tintColor: COLORS.white
                                            // tintColor: "#fff"
                                        }}
                                    />
                                ),
                                tabBarButton: (props) => (
                                    <CustomTabBarButton
                                        {...props}
                                        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('AddPet')}
                                    />
                                )
                            }}
                        />

                        <Tab.Screen
                            name="Message"
                            component={MessageScreen}
                            options={{
                                tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                                    <MaterialCommunityIcons
                                        name="inbox"
                                        color={color}
                                        size={30}
                                    />
                                )
                            }}
                        />

                        <Tab.Screen
                            name="Profile"
                            component={ProfileScreen}
                            options={{
                                tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (

                                    imageUser ? (
                                        loading ? (
                                            <ActivityIndicator size={20} color="black" />
                                        ) : (
                                            <Image
                                                style={{ borderRadius: 30, width: 30, height: 30 }}
                                                source={{ uri: imageUser }}
                                            />
                                        )

                                    ) : (
                                        <Image
                                            style={{ borderRadius: 30, width: 30, height: 30 }}
                                            source={require('../../assets/images/avatar-4.jpg')}
                                        />

                                    )
                                )
                            }} />
                    </>
                ) : (
                    null
                )
            }

        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
};

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const AppNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="HomeTabs" screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} independent={false}>
            <Stack.Screen name="HomeTabs" component={HomeTabs} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="EditProfile" component={EditProfileScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="AddPet" component={AddPetScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="PetDetail" component={PetDetailScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="EditPet" component={EditPetScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="PassivePets" component={PassivePets} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Favorite" component={FavoriteScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />        
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
};

export default AppNavigator;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    shadow: {
        shadowColor: '#7F5DF0',
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: 10,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.2,
        elevation: 5,
        shadowRadius: 3.5
    }
})
```

**AuthStorage.js**

```js
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const AuthToken = 'loggedIn';

const storeItem = async (value) => {
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(AuthToken, JSON.stringify(value));
        return true;
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
};

const getItem = async () => {
    try {
        const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem(AuthToken);
        return jsonValue != null ? JSON.parse(jsonValue) : null;
    } catch (e) {
        return null;
    }
};

export default { storeItem, getItem };
```

**signOut()**

```
 const signOut = async () => {
    await AuthStorage.storeItem('false').then(() => console.log('Clear'))    
}
```

Comment: use some global states, that can solve your this problem. Second thing you should clear asyncStorage on signout rather than saving other variable.

Comment: if i use mobx or redux this will solved problem right? and thanks for advice for clear i forgot to added :) @Kailash

Comment: const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState(false);, achieve this using mobx, this loginStatus should be your state and setLoginStatus should be a method to update the state loginStatus. You can update the loginStatus from any screen. This will get you to your solution.